# Migrate Craft CMS installation from PgSQL to MySQL - any hints?

Tags: migration, mysql, postgresql

We need to migrate a Craft installation with a pgsql dump to MySQL.

Any hints on the procedure?

Thanks,
Matthias

Comment: recently i saw a video - it's in 2018 though-, talking about migrating plugins from v2 to v3 but they talk about PostgreSQL from 1:42:00. maybe it helps from compatibility point of view. https://straightupcraft.com/events/migrating-a-website-with-plugins-from-craft-2-to-craft-3 but i want to know about dump and transition part myself.

Comment: I've tried it using a variety of tools... I think it's probably easier to export to a neutral format (JSON, XML, whatever) and re-import. None of the conversion tools I've used worked particularly well.

Comment: we made the same experiences, we tried 3 different tools. workbench, a commercial migration tool and a php based script. none of them brought us a clean mysql db without errors when accessing Craft and its website afterwards.

Comment: @MatthiasRedl-Mann I am really curious why did you want to migrate? Because I was looking the other way around, migrating from MySQL to Postgre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others finding this post: we never made it. We invested > 2 days and then decided to stay with postgresql for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Have never tried it (usually see people asking to go the other way from MySQL to PostgreSQL).

But after a quick Google search, I think the most promising option would be the migration tool built into MySQL Workbench (https://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/11/how-to-migrate-postgresql-databases-to-mysql-using-the-mysql-workbench-migration-wizard/).

Comment: we tried it, but had problems to get it to work...